# Why do all objects have the same date despite incrementing in each iteration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Hi I want to be able to modify an array of objects in state using a for loop and would like to know the best way of going about this!

```
const [ paymentData, setPaymentData ] = useState([
  {
    paymentN: 'First Payment',
    paymentDate: 'March 07'
  },
  {
    paymentN: 'Second Payment',
    paymentDate: 'March 24'
  },
  {
    paymentN: 'Third Payment',
    paymentDate: 'April 8th',
  },
  {
    paymentN: 'Fourth Payment',
    paymentDate: 'April 21st'
  }
])
```

Specifically I want to modify the dates in each object in my paymentData state array.
My intended final result would something like

```
{
paymentN: 'First Payment',
paymentDate: 'Mon Mar 14 2022 07:17:05 GMT-0400'
},
{
paymentN: 'Second Payment',
paymentDate: 'Mon Mar 28 2022 07:17:05 GMT-0400'

},
{
paymentN: 'Third Payment',
paymentDate: 'Mon Apr 11 2022 07:17:05 GMT-0400'
},
{
paymentN: 'Fourth Payment',
paymentDate: 'Mon Apr 25 2022 07:17:05 GMT-0400'
}
```

My function is intended to get the current date, increment it by 2 weeks and then set the new date at object[i]. My idea was to take the previous state data create a new array of objects with the modified date and set it to state again.

```
  const createPaymentPlan = ( amount, e )  => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentDate = new Date()
    var obj = []
    for ( let i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i ++ ) {
      
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+14)
      const updatedPaymentData = paymentData[i]
      updatedPaymentData.paymentDate = currentDate
      obj.push(updatedPaymentData)
      
    }

    setPaymentData(obj)
  }
```

When I tried this my final state looks like this, however when I console.log the updatedPaymentData variable it is set to the correct incremented date in each loop.

[image: Why does my state look like this where all the payment dates are equal to]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object is referring to the same date object causing all of them to have the same date after the loop. You can create a new Date in each iteration to fix this.

```js
const paymentData = [{
    paymentN: 'First Payment',
    paymentDate: 'March 07'
  },
  {
    paymentN: 'Second Payment',
    paymentDate: 'March 24'
  },
  {
    paymentN: 'Third Payment',
    paymentDate: 'April 8th',
  },
  {
    paymentN: 'Fourth Payment',
    paymentDate: 'April 21st'
  }
]
const currentDate = new Date()
const array = []
for (let i = 0; i < paymentData.length; i++) {
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14)
  const updatedPaymentData = paymentData[i]
  updatedPaymentData.paymentDate = new Date(currentDate);
  array.push(updatedPaymentData)
}
console.log(array)
```

---

It's better to make sure that the state's values are of the same type/format across renders so you can do this conversion and use the converted array as the initial state.

```
// this can be defined somewhere outside the component
const formatPaymentData = (paymentData) => {
  return paymentData.reduce(
    ((currentDate) => (formatted, curr) => {
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14);
      formatted.push({ ...curr, paymentDate: new Date(currentDate) });
      return formatted;
    })(new Date()),
    []
  );
};

const [paymentData, setPaymentData] = useState(
  formatPaymentData([
    {
      paymentN: 'First Payment',
      paymentDate: 'March 07',
    },
    {
      paymentN: 'Second Payment',
      paymentDate: 'March 24',
    },
    {
      paymentN: 'Third Payment',
      paymentDate: 'April 8th',
    },
    {
      paymentN: 'Fourth Payment',
      paymentDate: 'April 21st',
    },
  ])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const createPaymentPlan = ( amount, e )  => {
e.preventDefault();

let currentDate=new Date();
let finalPayment=paymentData.map((e)=>{
  currentDate=new Date(new Date().setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1))
   e.paymentDate=currentDate;
   return e
})

setPaymentData(finalPayment);
}
```